# Multi-dimension IReadOnlyDictionary typed using an interface for the inner value type

Tags: c#, dictionary, interface, covariance, contravariance

This is a little tricky to put into words, so I'll explain by example. The following code does not compile:

```
var data = new[] {
        new {Item = "abc", Values = new[] {1,2,3}},
        new {Item = "def", Values = new[] {1,2,3}}};

IReadOnlyDictionary<string, IReadOnlyDictionary<Guid, int>> target;

target = new ReadOnlyDictionary<string, IReadOnlyDictionary<Guid, int>>(
    data.ToDictionary(
            i => i.Item,
            v => new ReadOnlyDictionary<Guid, int>(
                v.Values.ToDictionary(
                    a => Guid.NewGuid(),
                    b => b))));
```

The error I get is:

```
The best overloaded method match for
    'ReadOnlyDictionary<string,IReadOnlyDictionary<Guid,int>>
        .ReadOnlyDictionary(IDictionary<string,IReadOnlyDictionary<System.Guid,int>>)'
has some invalid arguments
```

Yet if I declare target using a class instead of an interface for the inner values, it compiles:

```
IReadOnlyDictionary<string, ReadOnlyDictionary<Guid, int>> target;

target = new ReadOnlyDictionary<string, ReadOnlyDictionary<Guid, int>>(
    data.ToDictionary(
            i => i.Item,
            v => new ReadOnlyDictionary<Guid, int>(
                v.Values.ToDictionary(
                    a => Guid.NewGuid(),
                    b => b))));
```

Why can't I use an interface for the inner dictionary?

Comment: Your problem is that `IReadOnlyDictionary` isn't covariant, because of `KeyValuePair`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can cast the `ReadOnlyDictionary` to an `IReadOnlyDictionary`:

```
target = new ReadOnlyDictionary<string, IReadOnlyDictionary<Guid, int>>(
    data.ToDictionary(
            i => i.Item,
            v => (IReadOnlyDictionary<Guid, int>)new ReadOnlyDictionary<Guid, int>(
                v.Values.ToDictionary(
                    a => Guid.NewGuid(),
                    b => b))));
```

Or specify the interface type as a generic argument to `ToDictionary`:

```
target = new ReadOnlyDictionary<string, IReadOnlyDictionary<Guid, int>>(
    data.ToDictionary<string, IReadOnlyDictionary<Guid, int>>(
            i => i.Item,
            v => new ReadOnlyDictionary<Guid, int>(
                v.Values.ToDictionary(
                    a => Guid.NewGuid(),
                    b => b))));
```

Comment: Great! that fixed my problem... but I don't really get why the outer dictionary can implicitly cast, but the inner one can't...

Comment: Because of type inference, the inner dictionary was a `Dictionary<string, ReadOnlyDictionary<Guid, int>>`--you were returning a class, not an interface. That cannot be casted to a `Dictionary<string, IReadOnlyDictionary<Guid, int>>`. You might like to read about [covariance and contravariance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517.aspx).

Comment: Ok, thank you for your help. I think I'll need to read that article a few times before I can get my head around it!